# Using non-Django view in Django code

Tags: python, django

How to make a Django view based on a function outputting a page together with headers, like the following example function?

```
def f():
    print("Content-Type: text/plain\n\nExample.")
```

The best idea I've come up with is to redirect to a string, parse text of the output and recreate the response in Django format.

Are there better ways?

Comment: Why? Do you really want to construct the HTTP response from scratch? Then why are you using Django at all? If you want to do this you should get familiar with the HTTP spec. If you miss details, such as the requirement that line breaks must be `\r\n`, your HTTP will be invalid.

Comment: @HåkenLid I want to use BrainTree Python SDK (which is not Django-based) together with our Django project

Comment: If you want to return plain text instead of html, use a HttpResponse, like @souldeux suggests.

Comment: @HåkenLid I want to return whatever the function `f()` prints. It may be plain text, HTML, XML or whatsoever. The entire problem is to extract this data from the function

Comment: AFAIK the braintree python package does not use `print()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should highly consider solving the problem differently - i.e. modifying the original code: in python we prefer improving code over using patches to keep bad code alive.

If you fail with that, you can override `print` with your own callable which holds the output in a list of lines and creates an HTTP response with the captured output.  Keep in mind this is considered a last resort option...:

```
import builtins


def foo():
    print(1)
    print(2)
    print(3)


def bar():
    print_ = builtins.print

    buff = []

    def p(*pargs, **pkwargs):
        buff.append((pargs, pkwargs))

    builtins.print = p
    try:
        foo()
    finally:
        builtins.print = print_

    for x in buff:
        print(x)


bar()
```

(Assumes python 3)

Comment: How to "override" it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the results of these functions to build an [HttpResponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects).

Comment: Your answer would be complete, if you specified details HOW to do this

Comment: In the docs there is nothing about how to intercept `print` output and how to parse it to get separate headers and response body